# How to explain possitive/negative effect - choosing an appropriate model

Tags: r, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, lme4-nlme

I would be very thankful for your assistance on this.

I'm looking for a way to explain positive/negative effects on variable `probio`. 
So which covariates (`level`) explain the positive or negative `probio` values.

How I approached it so far. I'm using `R`.

I'm not sure how to explain the output of `summary(m)`.
I'm in doubts that this is how to approach this correctly. I'm grateful for any help and assistance.

```
m <- glm(probio~.+0,data=data.frame(Mdel))
summary(m)
Call:
glm(formula = probio ~ . + 0, data = data.frame(Mdel))

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-61.548   -8.724    0.000    9.732   62.198  

Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
prob_break0.2 -244.689     84.465  -2.897  0.00655 ** 
prob_break0.3 -215.498     74.966  -2.875  0.00693 ** 
prob_break0.4   -1.506     16.244  -0.093  0.92668    
prob_break0.5   42.612     14.255   2.989  0.00517 ** 
lmgrad0.98      -1.412     14.332  -0.099  0.92209    
lmgrad0.99     -20.191     17.879  -1.129  0.26668    
lmgrad1         11.281     36.459   0.309  0.75889    
lmgrad1.01      50.179     48.361   1.038  0.30678    
lmgrad1.02      48.934     55.642   0.879  0.38533    
lmgrad1.03      97.810     55.642   1.758  0.08777 .  
lmgrad1.04      81.850     55.642   1.471  0.15048    
lmgrad1.06     259.644     57.865   4.487 7.86e-05 ***
lmgrad1.07     217.539     66.964   3.249  0.00261 ** 
lmgrad1.08     195.997     69.733   2.811  0.00814 ** 
lmgrad1.09     153.855     74.593   2.063  0.04686 *  
lmgrad1.1      171.982     74.593   2.306  0.02736 *  
lmgrad1.11     241.497     79.857   3.024  0.00472 ** 
lmgrad1.12     267.690     79.857   3.352  0.00198 ** 
lmgrad1.13     249.755     72.011   3.468  0.00144 ** 
lmgrad1.14     139.637     61.237   2.280  0.02898 *  
qdist_lwr0.02  -16.588     14.920  -1.112  0.27403    
qdist_lwr0.03  -26.837     21.121  -1.271  0.21247    
qdist_lwr0.04  -78.199     24.453  -3.198  0.00299 ** 
qdist_lwr0.07  140.368     69.103   2.031  0.05010 .  
qdist_lwr0.08  105.052     72.664   1.446  0.15741    
qdist_lwr0.09   44.990     64.475   0.698  0.49006    
qdist_lwr0.1    62.833     38.915   1.615  0.11563    
qdist_lwr0.11       NA         NA      NA       NA    
qdist_upr0.02   12.744     15.235   0.836  0.40874    
qdist_upr0.03   91.931     33.591   2.737  0.00979 ** 
qdist_upr0.04       NA         NA      NA       NA    
qdist_upr0.05       NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 757.1818)

    Null deviance: 207490  on 63  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  25744  on 34  degrees of freedom
AIC: 617.59
```

#### Replication data and code

Data explained: The measurement process is repeated thousands of times, hence the sample data contains groups (3 groups). The respons variable is the `probio` value. The `probio` terminal value is always possitive (this is how it is setup, the cut off is always at possitive value. Sometimes it takes longer to converge to possitive number and hence there could be more observations in given group). The explanatory variables are i.e. `gradient`, `mean`, `probability of decline/increase`, `distance from mean value` etc.

```
 structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), probio = c(0, 35.5026959859765,   64.6089983931441, 
 85.834024338316, 59.6405957370915, -3.19270741588808, -27.7169149868533, 
-45.844521579671, 14.1408338672975, 88.22869955157, 114.028169014085, 
 105.514184796059, 151.876319553226, 168.067226890757, 0, -54.7708273277595, 
-38.8191849083461, 15.9690515283054, -62.1069878664421, -58.4963772130016, 
-76.7142037176031, -47.5228176145319, -51.2592921335846, -58.8248327203435, 
-43.229907539118, -82.576292115011, -91.5593705293273, -86.8013482849025, 
-83.7687101823067, -7.49944034027254, -24.0969231799017, -23.8748689113505, 
-8.72854233342985, -37.9360982556065, 1.56989392002544, 44.1046750955608, 
 30.1109707686755, 17.3232243695027, 42.8500361794506, 63.5742342710533, 
 0, 3.17914481004575, -24.4320127868477, -59.087251408208,  -79.6417276483759, 
-81.7533082376853, -30.9799259225386, -33.5117577088481,     -8.42153180835283, 
-9.67580366086846, 38.5560641248227, 26.1075949367092, -8.53553056858047, 
-32.0153673763412, -8.19354985547499, -23.9731500719193, -55.6002297530155, 
-44.1270860077022, -35.5851526385651, -16.4139974923062, 7.60050821308691, 
 17.9994566201778, 70.234788063446), qdist_upr = c(0.043263777134233, 
 0.0454848816029141, 0.0463422339452644, 0.0446999944597135, 0.041938971856514, 
 0.0394731730877036, 0.0390588792242721, 0.0383374539227541,    0.0371201267772996, 
 0.0345541476609046, 0.032278935378272, 0.0302182016486989,  0.026019251795149, 
 0.0240558330112297, 0.018013985782753, 0.0215161960668806, 0.0209508519340198, 
 0.0192071369571114, 0.0210849546754077, 0.0202095134608, 0.0191379477565783, 
 0.0198176936769832, 0.0204257958170224, 0.019563549874221, 0.017702225646931, 
 0.0154941127288175, 0.0134403129818519, 0.0130983612522226, 0.0139588726766278, 
 0.0128693496241277, 0.0115879222532105, 0.0116967035423587,  0.0108411132976565, 
 0.00970961649678159, 0.00950942252674425, 0.00948170968307704, 
 0.00995889750339063, 0.00954969872349154, 0.00985883230592033, 
 0.0110202740143615, 0.0108704265597483, 0.0111192367226658, 0.0116669206831725, 
 0.0125735455053511, 0.0136805794861807, 0.01478938473784, 0.0150383854330522, 
 0.0158370845752609, 0.0161519763582174, 0.0168664632775783, 0.016695099759559, 
 0.0166753752470929, 0.0121353615379898, 0.012707953222882,  0.0137183841959085, 
 0.0147327062728624, 0.0155893176737574, 0.0176183278830566, 0.0166012028954647, 
 0.0172783688079166, 0.018776231366511, 0.0189150681809029, 0.0286910620173424
 ), qdist_lwr = c(0.0828613220721155, 0.089228729508197,   0.0929452660547346, 
 0.0966873269688584, 0.100896545836801, 0.105779376173379,  0.0861126114589579, 
 0.0910407328904329, 0.0952483867362142, 0.0918685820688252,  0.0948440105676737, 
 0.0857849977560632, 0.0881588732048506, 0.0725574022828885,  0.0736764656061362, 
 0.0768711799251833, 0.0798376897326474, 0.0709080200477206, 0.0738804364810552, 
 0.0767604518169775, 0.0797939121468034, 0.0824452650386129, 0.0718684686904001, 
 0.0742989761133055, 0.0708989775616242, 0.0668830401416765, 0.0356276747293618, 
 0.0373020455419539, 0.0388840459101623, 0.0272968649749943, 0.0278809456713178, 
 0.0254200699619143, 0.025712294109751, 0.0194514317686783, 0.0194173418496557, 
 0.0154026137492662, 0.0149417664160234, 0.0134623799281939, 0.0143361676940799, 
 0.0159584759856388, 0.0147666694768374, 0.0154888882773336, 0.0171015909693695, 
 0.0158491484601655, 0.0206907746804863, 0.0272082541510483, 0.02101542812627, 
 0.0208879154247394, 0.0201312054599649, 0.0193522114212166, 0.0190913460235738, 
 0.0186788416203767, 0.0168317813191527, 0.0167394084244794, 0.0159231084330844, 
 0.0157713920877929, 0.0155320142934563, 0.0172731237298471, 0.0162134074941449, 
 0.0148705312726638, 0.0142371695343901, 0.0137109453326107,  0.013738104649325
 ), mprob = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 
 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
 0.4), lmgrad = c(1.14230880768917, 1.13462366993464, 1.12771262074022, 
 1.12137804996558, 1.11459434726307, 1.106572416083, 1.09820079985084, 
 1.08964908577009, 1.08262135315669, 1.07730898259395, 1.07263209942682, 
 1.06788094348028, 1.06415148339188, 1.06079386964281, 1.04233734326513, 
 1.03676549315289, 1.03173014746033, 1.02801110621948, 1.02285284971005, 
 1.0179689760525, 1.01290379904432, 1.00863952152666, 1.0044768615325, 
 1.00034884496868, 0.996724179658795, 0.992487794448527, 0.988281214385565, 
 0.984381509958762, 0.980736181482928, 0.978770365103859, 0.976602415720568, 
 0.974564882704027, 0.972940700260835, 0.97087065135898, 0.969702453094184, 
 0.96944619788269, 0.969008710892328, 0.968399829232819, 0.968344731914198, 
 0.968740302659922, 0.968857082324062, 0.969448337884105, 0.970583676938605, 
 0.972359985520614, 0.974497491532065, 0.97664135961822, 0.977814651648312, 
 0.979062131528571, 0.979841588232419, 0.980687911009954, 0.980627323473869, 
 0.980860451336057, 0.981803196149035, 0.983218844832308, 0.984206055221526, 
 0.985532800637601, 0.98748283592687, 0.989233434003679, 0.990845446134589, 
 0.992117099000128, 0.992966445360489, 0.993663785360577, 0.993392047626788
 )), .Names = c("group", "probio", "qdist_upr", "qdist_lwr", "mprob", 
"lmgrad"), row.names = c("20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", 
"78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", 
"89", "90"), class = "data.frame")

# Data processing part:
sampdat$prob_break <- as.factor(round(sampdat$mprob,1))
sampdat$lmgrad <- as.factor(round(sampdat$lmgrad,2))
sampdat$qdist_lwr <- as.factor(round(sampdat$qdist_lwr,2))
sampdat$qdist_upr <- as.factor(round(sampdat$qdist_upr,2))
Mdel <- model.matrix(~ probio + prob_break + lmgrad + qdist_lwr + qdist_upr + 0, sampdat)
```